# Related paths for dependencies in RequireJS define

Tags: javascript, requirejs

In a requirejs module, i want to load some related files as dependencies. That files are in the same folder as module with define(). The module and related files maybe move to another location.

How can i set define's dependencies by related paths?

`movableModule.js` now:

```
define('movableModule', [
    "changable/path/to/my/modules/relatedFile1",
    "changable/path/to/my/modules/relatedFile2"
    ], function(){
        console.log("movableModule loaded");
});
```

`movableModule.js` i want to be like this:

```
define('movableModule', [
    "./relatedFile1",
    "./relatedFile2"
    ], function(){
        console.log("movableModule loaded relatively!");
});
```

As i know calling `require.config` and using `baseUrl` will change all routes in all modules, yes? and if no, i don't know how to use it in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should configure RequireJS to define your different paths.
Then you could request those module, just by their name :

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "/",
    paths: {
        "relatedFile1": "changable/path/to/my/modules/relatedFile1"
    }
});
```

Then you'll be able to do :

```
define('movableModule', [
    "relatedFile1"
    ], function(){
        console.log("movableModule loaded");
});
```

Also, as mentionned in comments, you can define a partial path, and use it later for your incoming modules :

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "/",
    paths: {
        "modulePath": "changable/path/to/my/modules/"
    }
});
```

And require your modules like that :

```
define('movableModule', [
    "modulePath/module1",
    "modulePath/module2"
    ], function(){
        console.log("movableModule loaded");
});
```

[Comment from the developer.](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/issues/230#issuecomment-5269562)

Comment: Isn't there any way to don't mention relatedFiles in global require.config? modules will be added after completing development and  it will be very simpler and cleaner to mention movableModule.js only. I want paths be related to main module file.

Comment: In this config, I think you can add a partial path. This way you could declare something like `modulePath:'changeable/path/to/my/modules'` and then require them via `'modulePath/relatedFile'`. But this needs confirmation.

Comment: I think it works like that, as commented by the developer here : https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/issues/230#issuecomment-5269562